Weird error when redefining \msg_info_text:n and using fontspec package
I am still experimenting with LaTeX3 to get a better understanding. I follow the L3 manual for this.
Now to my problem: I want to redefine \msg_X_text:n like explained in 11.3.
Everything works perfectly fine but the moment I try to include the fontspec package I get the followng weird error and I have no clue how to resolve it:

main.tex:18: Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
 ???
! ERROR: Negative argument for \prg_replicate:nn.
l.18 \begin{document}
If you say, e.g., \def\a1{...}', then you must always put 1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.


I never used \prg_replicate:nn within my code nor did I define a1.
The error only occurs when redefining \msg_info_text:n, all other redefinitions work fine.
I know for a fact that it has to do something with fontspec's logging because the error resolves itself once I comment out one of the following 2 lines:
\cs_gset_nopar:Nn \msg_info_text:n {INFO} % or
\RequirePackage{fontspec}


Also: fontspec indeed does log exactly after the error with my redefinition ("INFO"):


INFO: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).

Below is my MWE:
main.tex
\documentclass{MYCLASS}

\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}

myclass.cls
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023-11-01]
\ProvidesExplClass{MYCLASS}{2024-05-05}{1}{description here}

\LoadClass{minimal} % --> needed for a successful compilation

\cs_gset:Nn \msg_fatal_text:n {FATAL}
\cs_gset:Nn \msg_critical_text:n {CRITICAL}
\cs_gset:Nn \msg_error_text:n {ERROR}
\cs_gset:Nn \msg_warning_text:n {WARNING}
\cs_gset:Nn \msg_info_text:n {INFO} % comment out and the error is gone

\RequirePackage{fontspec} % comment out and the error is gone

\endinput

log file (shortened):
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.3.31) (format=lualatex 2024.4.27)  5 MAY 2024 22:53
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
Document Class: MYCLASS 2024-05-05 v1 description here
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
Package: xparse 2024-03-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
Package: fontspec 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2024/02/13 2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: fontspec-luatex 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

main.tex:18: Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???  
      ! ERROR: Negative argument for \prg_replicate:nn.
l.18 \begin{document}
                   
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

INFO: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this). <--- fontspec logged this with my redefined \msg_info_text:n

EDIT 1:
I've used @UlrikeFischers approach but after using additional packages Im wondering why only fontspec switches its text not other packages like babel or microtype:
myclass.tex
\cs_gset:Nn \msg_info_text:n {INFO~(#1)}

log file
Package babel Info: You haven't specified a language as a class or package
(babel)             option. I'll load 'nil'. Reported on input line 4267.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `item' on input line 18.
INFO (fontspec): Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).


Notice: Switiching \cs_gset:Nn to \cs_gset_protected:Nn resolves this error but \msg_info_text:n does not expand in the log file: \msg_info_text:n {fontspec}: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).

the code doesn't expect the message (INFO) to be shorter as the module name (fontspec) as the module name is normally (and imho should) always be included too. With something like \cs_gset:Nn \msg_info_text:n {INFO~(#1)} it will work again.

@egreg the docu writes that it can be redefined to change the language.

@UlrikeFischer But not that way. The kernel definition of \msg_fatal_text:n is not just a string of text. Similarly for the others. Possibily the documentation should be clarified…

Would you mind explaining why you want to do this? It means you lose all indication of the cause of problems from any code which uses these messages.

@cfr If I understood correctly the motivation is "I am still experimenting with LaTeX3 to get a better understanding" i.e. it's for educational purpose.

@user202729 OK, but people tend to experiment in ways they see some use for, so it doesn't seem an illegitimate question. Maybe the answer is just 'well, I wanted to see what broke', but maybe it is something else better achieved in some other manner.

@egreg I quite agree, the whole idea that it can be redefined sounds a bit odd. It is quite unclear how that can be used to change the language. Also all messages are in english, so why allow localization there in the first place?

@UlrikeFischer Thanks for claraification, I'll mark your comment as solution.

@cfr I actually come from a different domain, namely c++, and just wanted to try out what is possible with l3msg; and for this I oriented myself on c++ logging libraries, which mostly use the error designation "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", .... So I just stuck with it.

@egreg Yes, the manual refers to the use of \msg_X_text:n for language-related circumstances. However, as I understand the explanations in the manual, the functions "only" generate standard text, which I can change at will. So if I wanted to, I could point \msg_see_documentation_text:n to my git repository for example, at least that's my understanding. Whether that was/is the intention, probably not...

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer:

the code doesn't expect the message (INFO) to be shorter as the module name (fontspec) as the module name is normally (and imho should) always be included too. With something like \cs_gset:Nn \msg_info_text:n {INFO~(#1)} it will work again.

